# Combine CollectionChanged and PropertyChanged notifications in ObservableForPropertyHelper with ReactiveUI

Tags: wpf, system.reactive, reactiveui

I have a ReactiveObject ViewModel that contains an IObservableCollection and a regular property that raises INPC when it is modified (ie, vanilla WPF).

I want to implement an ObservableForPropertyHelper backed read-only that will re-evaluate whenever the regular property changes, or the collection changes (raises its CollectionChanged) event.

I know I can implement this using WhenAnyValue for the regular property, FromEventPattern to create an observable for the collectionchanged event, and then stitching them together with a CombineLatest.  My question is - is there a less god-awful way to do this?  Is there a built in ReactiveUI functionality that will help me achieve this?

Comment: Please provide the "god-awful" implementation in your code and then we can try to improve it for you. Right now it's difficult to determine what you actually want and a god-awful amount of work for us to try guess what you want. Please make it easy for us to answer you.

Answer (score 0):

You could swap the ObservableCollection for ReactiveUI's ReactiveCollection which exposes an IObservable for when the collection changes.

You could also use ReactiveUI's ObservableForProperty instead of WhenAny, which will be a little more succinct as you are only observing 1 property.

Other than that, what you have described is how I would do it.